# GA4 Measurement protocol IP override

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-4

When sending events to GA4 is there a way to override user ip, if using universal analytics you could have passed a user_ip variable `uip` but for GA4 I dont see a param option to pass user ip. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

OK found a temporary solution [here](https://github.com/dataunlocker/save-analytics-from-content-blockers/issues/25).

instead of `&uip=x.x.x.x` in the url, add `&_uip=x.x.x.x`.

> Google tends to prefix alpha/beta URL parameters with underscore _

Comment: Doesn't seems to be working anymore

Comment: @CodePanda at least `/g/collect` works for me. Did you try specifying both `uip` and `_uip`?

Answer (score -5):

No parameter is necessary:

> **For Google Analytics 4 properties, IP anonymization is enabled by
> default**. The content provided below describes the IP anonymization
> process for legacy Google Analytics tags.

[Source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en)

So this isn't even handled on the level of code (i.e. you couldn't enable it if you tried), it's built into the property.

Comment: This assumes you are using gtag to send events, im talking about using measurement protocol

Comment: This assumes your property is GA4. This is built-in at the property level, not something you set inside your request.

Comment: Btw. it has been this way since the beginning when it was still called App&Web. If you do not believe me, would you believe GTM/GA Guru Simo Ahava? https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/getting-started-with-google-analytics-app-web/ - look in the comments (I know, appeal to authority, but he is Google Developers Experts and has work with that pretty much from the start).

Comment: IP anonymization masks the given IP. IP override is another thing. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en

Comment: @MohammadNikravan you are obviously right and I have no idea how I came up with that answer.